# Modernize my JSP web application

Tags: java, jsp, architecture, ejb

I have developed an application using JSP and classes. My JSP's have java code that make calls to my Java classes to save data in a MySQL Database.

I know that nowadays this is a bad practice but that's the way I learned I now I want to add a new module to the application and I would like to start using modern architectures.

I would like to have your advices about this things:

1. What architecture should I use in order to create the new module using modern patterns but keeping compatibility with the already developed site.
2. What technology or framework should I use? I was thinking about using EJB's and JPA for the business logic and JSF with Primefaces for the "client" side (But I have realized that it's too difficult to integrate my already created css styles with the primefaces elements).

Note: Possibly in the future we will need to develop an android application to capture the data of the new module. Please have this in mind.

I appreciate your advices and any information about related things like session management, css styles already created or something else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Using JSP is not a bad practice at all, If you have existing application that already works fine (performance, maintenance, etc) then let it be in JSP Thats the technology you need.

in that case your answers will be.

1. existing architecture,
2. existing technologies and frameworks

However if you decide to change the architecture, You shouldn't just concentrate on tools and frameworks which are not the architecture.

You have to think about, reliability and consistency, Security, maintainability, scalability, availability, Interoperability, performance, Compliance, User experience and more to decide on the architecture, Just because there is buzz in the market is not a good reason to decide on the architecture.